# how to make fail2ban read json docker logs

Tags: logging, nginx, docker, docker-compose, fail2ban

Is it possible to configure my fail2ban jail.conf to inspect the docker logs instead of mounting the log in the host.  for example to set the logpath to the path of the log of the container.

Jail.conf:

```
...
#example
[nginx-http-auth]
    enabled = true
    filter  = nginx-http-auth
    port    = http,https
    logpath = /var/lib/docker/containers/819564257d4*/*e0923e-json.log
...
```

but this doesn't do much, because there is a little difference between the docker logs command and the log file:

```
# docker logs @nginx_container_name
```

> 2016/03/23 12:39:52 [error] 6#6: *350 upstream prematurely closed
>   connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   **@ATTACKER_IP**, server: **@MY_DNS**, request: "GET /Blog/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.3:8001/Blog/wp-login.php", host:
>   "**@MY_IP:80"**
>   **@ATTACKER_IP** - - [23/Mar/2016:12:39:52 +0000] "GET /Blog/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"

```
# cat /var/lib/docker/containers/819564257d4*/*e0923e-json.log
```

> {"log":"2016/03/23 12:39:52 [error] 6#6: *350 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: **@ATTACKER_IP**, server: **@MY_DNS**, request: \"GET /Blog/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1\", upstream: \"http://172.17.0.3:8001/Blog/wp-login.php\", host: \"**@MY_IP**:80\"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2016-03-23T12:39:52.219982304Z"}
>   {"log":"**@ATTACKER_IP** - - [23/Mar/2016:12:39:52 +0000] \"GET /Blog/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1\" 502 173 \"-\" \"Python-urllib/2.7\"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2016-03-23T12:39:52.421767592Z"}

I'm accually mounting the log file into the host and I know that this is stupid, so my question is :

- is there any way to make the rsyslog read the json log file of the
  docker nginx container
- if not, how to configure docker to make a syslog log format
- if not , how to configure syslog on the container in order to pass
  the log to my host ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a container to send logs to syslog, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/

Comment: I'm actually running my containers with docker-compose, and the docs are a little ambiguous, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the fail2ban regex rules for the **nginx-http-auth** daemon.
The regex rules are in this folder:

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d
```